# Microsot Visual C++ Runtime Library Error upon Converting a File through VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player, video-conversion

I always used HandBrake for video conversion (compression) which works great, but today I found an [**answer on quora**](http://www.quora.com/What-are-some-good-computer-tricks-that-are-not-commonly-known/answer/Abhishek-Gupta-733) which explains how to convert videos through vlc, when I converted through VLC, the results were better than handbrake.
But I wanted to batch convert files (multiple files at a time), which was possible in VLC's V-3 (nightly version) which I downloaded from [nightlies.videolan.org](http://nightlies.videolan.org/).

The problem I face is when I convert a file, the process is done smoothly until it reaches the end, where it shows the following error (shown in the image) and the converted file isn't usable.

Edit: I tried both 32 bit and 64 bit version of the software, and I am using windows 7 home premium 64 bit.

[image: Visual C++ runtime error for VLC video conversion]

Comment: Are you using the nightly version of VLC?

Comment: Yes I'm using the nightly version of VLC, because the stable version 2.x.x doesn't have the feature of batch conversion.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to file a bug with the VLC team. You're using pre-release software and it's expected to have bugs.

Comment: I already posted a bug report, but I don't know when they'll respond or fix it.

Comment: Just so you know, questions regard pre-release software are typically considered off-topic here (there have been [several](http://meta.superuser.com/q/6926/820) [discussions](http://meta.superuser.com/q/7226/820) on the topic on meta).  They tend to generate questions that are very specific to a particular build of the software and are not very helpful to the general community.  Its usually best to keep these kinds of question on the development forums for the software.